# Embedding PHP coding into Contact Form 7 and Contact Form 7 Cost Calculator - Price Calculation

Tags: php, wordpress, contact-form-7

I'm using the [Contact Form 7](https://en-gb.wordpress.org/plugins/contact-form-7/) and the [Contact Form 7 Cost Calculator - Price Calculation](https://wordpress.org/plugins/cf7-cost-calculator-price-calculation/) plugin.

Is there a way I could use PHP in order to manipulate operations.  For example:

```
if(input_text_value>20){
    // Do Something
}
```

Comment: I have been working on a new calculator plugin which allows you to dynamically define your functions in a mathematical editor which are then converted to PHP code for interpretation.  The plugin also allows you to define constants, variable input field values, and conversion factors using dropdown selects.  Although the calculator is currently in a stable versions, it has yet to be released on the official repo and therefore has not documentation associated with it.  You can take a look at it on github: https://github.com/aurovrata/cf7-calc

Answer (score 0):

[Cost calculator Contact form 7](https://wordpress.org/plugins/cost-calculator-contact-form-7/) is new version of that plugin it can release now days to setup for our site. i did check it make much user friendly